# Why Krishna was not worthy of syamantaka jewel?

Tags: krishna, vishnu-purana

In the *Vishnu Purana fourth section eighth chapter* the story of syamantaka jewel is present. At last Krishna said that he was not worthy of syamantaka jewel.[image]

I want to know reason that why Lord Krishna was not worthy for syamantaka jewel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Viṣṇu Purāṇa itself gives [the reason](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc116010.html):

> **But this jewel**, to be of advantage to the whole kingdom, **should be taken charge of by a person who leads a life of perpetual continence**: if worn by an impure individual, it will be the cause of his death.
>
> **Now as I have sixteen thousand wives, I am not qualified to have the care of it.**
> It is not likely that Satyabhāmā will agree to the conditions that would entitle her to the possession of the jewel; and as to Balabhadra, he is too much addicted to wine and the pleasures of sense to lead a life of self-denial.

Comment: Still Krishna is called Akhanda Brahmachari no?